# use osg to save the rendering result of the text model as a png image,but failed

Tags: c++

I am a New to osg,When I tried to use osg to save the rendering result of the text model as a png image, I found that the run() function must be called to save to the png image. May I ask how to save the rendering result to the png image without calling the run() function?

this is my code:

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> tempgrp1 = new osg::Group;
SetTunnelGroup(tunnelname, fontstyle, tempgrp1, 1);
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> image = new 
osg::ref_ptr<osgViewer::Viewer> viewer1 = new osgViewer::Viewer();
viewer1->setSceneData(tempgrp1);
viewer1->realize();
viewer1->getCamera()->attach(osg::Camera::COLOR_BUFFER, image);//

viewer1->run();

std::string filename1 = ("text_image.png");
image->setFileName(filename1);
osgDB::writeImageFile(*(image), filename1);
```

I try to call the frame() function to replace the run() function, but the saved png image is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can use `osgViewer::Viewer::frame()`. First, set up the viewer and camera as you have already done. Then, instead of calling `viewer1->run()`, call `viewer1->frame()` to render a single frame. After that, you can save the image to a file using `osgDB::writeImageFile()`:

```cpp
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> tempgrp1 = new osg::Group;
SetTunnelGroup(tunnelname, fontstyle, tempgrp1, 1);
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> image = new osg::Image;
osg::ref_ptr<osgViewer::Viewer> viewer1 = new osgViewer::Viewer();
viewer1->setSceneData(tempgrp1);
viewer1->realize();
viewer1->getCamera()->attach(osg::Camera::COLOR_BUFFER, image);

// call frame() instead of run()
viewer1->frame();

std::string filename1 = ("text_image.png");
image->setFileName(filename1);
osgDB::writeImageFile(*(image), filename1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used   osgViewer::Viewer::frame()，but I found that the saved picture  has no text. I try to set some parameters to  Viewer1 , but it still  has no text